# Is there a way with Django's ModelAdmin to display a different field when rendering a ManyToMany select box?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django model with a `ManyToManyField`.

When rendering the admin page to add an instance of the model, `ModelAdmin` renders a select box with options like `SomeModel object(7c158809-4c9b-4d44-b3ac-9f225b8bd076` (the model uses a uuid as its primary key).

How can I get Django admin to render the select box with a different, more friendly field?

Answer (score 1):

Despite of last answer, if your Django version is greater than 2.0 one optimize and clean way is to define an admin page for your `SomeModel`. Just like following codes:

```
@admin.register(SomeModel)
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'created_time', ) # change this part to your fields
    search_fields = ('name', ) # If you have this field in your model
```

And then in your source model admin codes (where this model has a M2M relation to `SomeModel`) add an attribute as `auto_complete_fields` (which is added to Django from version 2) and reference it to `SomeModelAdmin`. Something like following codes:

```
@admin.register(SourceModel)
class SourceModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "created_time", )
    search_fields = ('name', )
    autocomplete_fields = ['some_model_field', ] # i.e. your M2M field in that model
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution occurred to me as I was typing the question. Django admin is just displaying a string representation of the model in the select box.  Adding a `__str__` definition to the model with however you want the object to be rendered in the select box will fix the issue, like so:

```py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # ... field definitions, including something like name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Example, it will definitely clear your doubt to render related fields on admin site.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

@admin.register(models.Profile)  #Decorator
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ['first_name','last_name','membership','phone','birth_date'] #Columns to display
    list_select_related=['user'] #To avoid extra queries

def first_name(self,profile):
    return profile.user.first_name #Foreign key relationship

def last_name(self,profile):
    return profile.user.last_name  #Foreign key relationship
```

In this example I am rendering Profile Model, In which user is Foreign Key to User Model, and User model contains first_name, last_name.